# How to handle push notification allow from settings in iOS

Tags: ios, swift3, apple-push-notifications

I have Integrated the push notification in my app. I am getting the device token in my `AppDelegate` and sending to the server in my `LoginViewController`. When alert comes if user click on "Don't allow" I am not calling my device registration service. But I have no idea how to handle this scenario.

> If user click on don't allow in the push notification alert and go inside the app, then he open device settings and enable the push notification.

In this case how can I call my device registration service?
Please help me
Thanks

Comment: The device registration method will be called every time you register your app for notifications. So after the setting change, when you launch the app again and it registers for receiving notifications, the method would be called.

Comment: @lostInTransit Thanks. If user changed the settings and reopen the app,, when it comes from background to foreground, in that case also it can register?

Comment: You will have to make sure you call the `registerForRemoteNotifications` method

Answer (score 4):

Actually there is no delegate for it to observe that user changed the status for push notifications.

But you can check by using this method in `applicationDidBecomeActive:` method like this

**Objective C :**

iOS 8 and above

```
   if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications]){
        NSLog(@"push notifications are disabled");
}
```

For iOS 10

```
UIRemoteNotificationType types = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];

if (types == UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone) {
    NSLog(@"push notifications are disabled");
}
```

**Swift :**

iOS 8 and above

```
let isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications = UIApplication.shared.isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications
if isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications {
    NSLog(@"push notifications are enabled");
} else {
    NSLog(@"push notifications are disabled");
}
```

For iOS 10

```
let current = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

current.getNotificationSettings(completionHandler: { (settings) in

    if settings.authorizationStatus == .denied {
    NSLog(@"push notifications are disabled");
    }
})
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

***Note***

Any changes in the settings restart the app. 
so If user turn on the notification from settings then your app will be restarted and you will get the device token in app-delegate and you can send it to your server. if your login is save locally and you were sending device_token in login api, then you need to use a separate service to send device_token to server.

Comment: But when I open the app and change settings still its running in the background. doesn't seems its restarting

Answer (score -1):

In AppDelegate

If user Allow Notification, the token will be returned in func bellow and you will call your service to sending to your server

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
}
```

If user Don't Allow Notification, you will receive error in func bellow

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {

}
```

Comment: yeas what I am asking in the scenario I mentioned.. then how to get notification withou tclosing and reopen the app since I haven tcall to my service device registration service since user didnt allow when it prompt

Comment: when you open app, you alway reviece token in func didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken with real device,
you will send token to your server,

when you send notification to user, device auto show notification if user allow notificaion and will not show if user don't notificaion